# What is/was the IMP team? (related to Mars Pathfinder)

Tags: nasa, pathfinder

The Astronomy Picture to of the Day for 2000 May 14 titled [A Presidential Panorama of Mars](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap000514.html) credits the panoramic image to:

- [IMP Team](http://imp.lpl.arizona.edu/imp/team/team.html)
- [JPL](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/)
- [NASA](http://www.nasa.gov/)

but the first link does not seem to work.

> Explanation: Scroll right to unfold one of the great panoramas ever taken on the surface of Mars. For best viewing, click and hold the right arrow icon at the bottom of your browser window. This image, dubbed a "presidential panorama" by the Mars Pathfinder team, shows in colorful detail the surroundings of the Sagan Memorial Station.

**Question:** What is the IMP team (related to Mars Pathfinder), what work do/did they do, and is there a better link to read about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Wayback Machine archiv](https://web.archive.org/web/20010803105814/http://imp.lpl.arizona.edu:80/imp/team/team.html)e of your first link, IMP refers to Imager for Mars Pathfinder, or the lander camera from Mars Pathfinder. The team was mainly based at University of Arizona Lunar and Planetary Laboratory, the location that primarily built the camera.

## University of Arizona:

Peter Smith; *Principal Investigator*

Dan Britt; *Project Manager and Geology*

Robert Singer; *Spectroscopy*

Martin Tomasko, Lyn Doose; *Atmosphere*

## Max Planck Institute for Aeronomy, Lindau,Germany:

H. Uwe Keller; *Atmosphere*

## United States Geological Survey:

Laurence Soderblom; *Spectroscopy*

## Arizona State University:

Ronald Greeley; *Geology*

## Niels Bohr Insitute, Denmark:

Jens Martin Knudsen; *magnets*

## Technical University of Braunschweig, Germany:

Fritz Gliem; *Data Compression*

### From the IMP homepage, page titled "Anatomy: Dissecting an IMP Image" ([archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20010702203637/http://imp.lpl.arizona.edu:80/imp/anatomy)):

The "Presidential Pan" is a full color 360° panorama made of 395 small images. Each image is actually three filtered B&W images combined to an RGB color image. The individual 248x256 pixel color images are parallax adjusted by members of the IMP team, and stitched together to create the whole panorama.

Unfortunately many of the example images from the site, and all from the Anatomy page are missing.

Comment: Great answer and detective work; thank you very much!